# How find this integral $I=\int\int_{D}|\cos{(x+y)}|dxdy$

Tags: integration

Find this 
$$
I
=
\int\int_{D}\left\vert\,\cos\left(x + y\right)\right\vert\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y
$$
where
$D
=
\left\{\vphantom{\Large A}\left(x, y\right)\quad
\left.\right\vert\quad
\ \left\vert\,x\,\right\vert + \left\vert\,y\,\right\vert\ \leq\ 2\pi\right\}$

My try: let $$x+y=u,x-y=v\Longrightarrow x=\dfrac{u+v}{2},y=\dfrac{u-v}{2}$$
then
$J=\left|\begin{vmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}\\
\dfrac{1}{2}&-\dfrac{1}{2}
\end{vmatrix}\right|=\dfrac{1}{2}$
and
$D'=\{(x,y)||u+v|+|u-v|\le 2\pi\}$

then
$$I=\dfrac{1}{2}\int\int_{D'}|\cos{u}|dudv$$

and Follow I can't,Thank you for can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $D': -2\pi\leq u\leq 2\pi,\quad -2\pi\leq v\leq 2\pi$.

Comment: why?Thank you very much

Comment: i think he's doing:

$|x+y| \leq |x|+|y| \leq 2\pi$ but this implies $u=|x+y| \leq 2\pi$

But i don't understand these substitutions quite well yet.

Comment: @nanchangjian: there are four possibilities $x+y\leq2\pi$, $-x-y\leq2\pi$, $x-y\leq2\pi$ and $y-x\leq 2\pi$. Collecting these and recalling $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$ you will arrive at $D'$.